# How to take input in list in python in which all input are in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

```
s=input().split()
n,m=int(s[0]),int(s[1])
arr=(int(i) for i in s[2:])
```

input like

```
3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

in this first two are row and column
and remaining are 2d list element

output be like

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
s = input().split()
s = list(map(int, s))
[s[2 + (i - 1) * s[1]: 2 + i * s[1]] for i in range(1, s[0] + 1)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code:

```py
arr = list(arr)
blocks = [arr[i:i+m] for i in range(0, len(arr), m)]
assert len(blocks) == n
```

Answer (score 0):

If [numpy](https://numpy.org/) is an option, you can simply reshape the 1D array:

```
s = input().split()
n,m = int(s[0]),int(s[1])
arr = numpy.array(s[2:], dtype=int).reshape((n,m))
```

You can output it as a numpy array

```
print(arr)
# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
#       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

or convert it to a nested list

```
print(arr.tolist())
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```